# document.location.href is not copying the exact URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

This is a generic question.

I have a visualforce page where the URL is customized i.e. some expilcit parameters have been added to it.

In a visualforce page popup I am adding the following. I have also tried using other variations of this piece of code

window.location = document.location.href;

The problem with is is that it is not taking the exact URL including all the parameters.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Visualforce also uses POST parameters, so there's not necessarily a pure JavaScript solution. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am trying to refresh the parent page on a button click within a popup. So I am trying to fetch the exact parent page URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this?

In controller:

```
public String redirectUrl {public get; private set;}

redirectUrl = '/' + currentQ.Id +'?additionalParameters';
```

In VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!someAction}" value="Save Changes" id="saveButton" oncomplete="refreshPage();"/>`


    <script>
    function refreshPage(){
        window.top.location.href =  '{!redirectUrl}';
    }
    </script>
```